# Bizarre character in python string

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I am reading the contents of a file and one of the characters is an unknown character. I copied the part of the file that had this unknown character to my text editor and created the following script. I uploaded an image of the script because I'm not able to paste this character on SO, it shows up empty. The unknown character is '<0x01>' in the image. What is this character? What is the proper way to remove this character and other characters like them?

```
x = "<0x01> hello"

print x.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print x.replace("<0x01>", "")
```

[image]

[image: You can see the image in the description now]

Python 2.7.6

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: defined encoding when reading file?

Comment: Could you maybe post your code instead of images?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GWNMf1fZ

Comment: @mnm Welcome to SO! However, please put the code in the question itself.  Links don't last forever, and it's easier to answer the question if you don't need to follow a link.

Comment: That's a Control-A character that somehow got inserted into your file.  The normal way you'd write that character in a Python string would be `"\x01"`.  The `<0x01>` appears to be your editor's way of showing unprintable characters, that's not something that you can type in yourself.